# Where was Chrome Extension installed from?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Have an extension that has a good number of installs 10k+ and I'd like to open up a walkthrough page after it's installed from the Chrome Webstore only.

The problem is I never requested the `tabs` permission when I initially deployed it, so requesting that permission now (in order to lookup the focused tab's url and determine if the install happened from the Chrome Webstore host) causes problems because then all existing installs will have the extension disabled when the auto-update rolls out (due to the new permission request).

Are there any other ways of determining if the install is coming from the Chrome Webstore? I'm not trying to bypass any legit privacy/permission issues. Rather, looking for a technique that allows me to open a window only when it's needed.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: I don't see why knowing the source would help you because Chrome confirms the permissions before actually updating the extension so you won't see the update until it's confirmed. See [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) for a possible workaround.

Comment: With the `tabs` permission you can access the URL of the tab that is active. If this tab is coming from the host `chrome.google.com` it's a safe bet that it's a Chrome Webstore install, at which point I can open up the onboarding URL.

Comment: I tried the optional permissions approach, but the issue with that is only a user gesture can request them. And since I need this at install-time from the webstore, it's technically not a gesture.